# Passing parameter to controller using jquery

Tags: java, jquery

I have created a view and controller, I am trying to pass the form parameters to controller using jquery..

```
  $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "add.htm", 
    datatype: "json",
    data: "name=" + name + "&password=" + password + "&gender=" + gender + "&aboutyou=" + aboutyou, 
    success: function(response){
        alert(response.name);
      // we have the response 
      if(response.status == "SUCCESS"){
          $('#info').html("User has been added to the list successfully");
          /* $('#name').val('');
          $('#education').val(''); */
      }else{
          $('#info').html("Sorry, there is some thing wrong with the data provided.");
      }       
    },  
    error: function(e){  
      alert('Error: ' + e);  
    }  
  });  
}
```

Here is my controller.

```
      public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, employee employee) throws Exception {
    List list=new ArrayList();
    employeedao.saveUser(employee);
    return new ModelAndView("userform");
}
```

Comment: good try... but what is the question?

Comment: my form values are not passing to controller from jquery...

Comment: name,password,gender,and about you parameters are not passing from jquery to controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to get the values in the controller(from the question title),If this is the requirement then use `request.getParameter("parametername");`

For example to get the name do this

```
request.getParameter("name");
```

also you need to change the format for passing the parameter's like

`data:{parametername:parametervalue}` as its a JSON

example `data:{name:name ....}`

Comment: Not relevant to the OP's question I thinks

Comment: @user2310289 from the title I assumed this and the json format is also wrong,

Comment: thanks..but my alert(response.name) is not working ...getting undefined..

Comment: good spotting about json format

Comment: @mohittomar did you change to JSON format?

Comment: @mohittomar Glad it helped,If you have any other questions feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

replace Your below line:-

```
 data: "name=" + name + "&password=" + password + "&gender=" + gender + "&aboutyou=" + aboutyou,
```

with the below line:-

```
 data: { name:name,password:password,gender:gender,aboutyou:aboutyou}
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of your data is incorrect

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

It is in the format of

```
{ name: "John", time: "2pm" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have sent the data like normal one but in jquery the format is varied as mentioned below

```
$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: "add.htm", 
datatype: "json",
data: { "name":name,"password":password,"gender":gender,"aboutyou":aboutyou},
success: function(response){
    alert(response.name);
  // we have the response 
  if(response.status == "SUCCESS"){
      $('#info').html("User has been added to the list successfully");
      /* $('#name').val('');
      $('#education').val(''); */
  }else{
      $('#info').html("Sorry, there is some thing wrong with the data provided.");
  }       
},  
error: function(e){  
  alert('Error: ' + e);  
}  
  });  
}
```

This is the format for sending data.
Thanks
Naveen